# Why is this django template tag failing to display?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template tag located in catalog/templatetags/catalog_tags.py, which looks like this:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("tags/navigation.html")
def nav_links():
    flatpage_list = FlatPage.objects.all()
    return {'flatpage_list': flatpage_list }
```

I have a catalog.html which has `{% load catalog_tags %}`, to load that tag, and is followed by an inclusion tag for my navigation, `{% include "tags/navigation.html" %}`.

navigation.html contains the following:

```
{% with flatpage_list as pages %}
{% for page in pages %}
    <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

But the list of flat_pages is not appearing in my navigation section.  Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, with your current state you have something liek this in `catalog.html` template:

```
{% load catalog_tags %}
 .....
{%  include "tags/navigation.html" %}
```

What this code does, is just *renders* the "tags/navigation.html" template, nothing more. So your custom template tag is not hit at all. To fix it, you should replace `include` with `nav_links`:

```
{% load catalog_tags %}
 .....
{% nav_links %}
```

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags) for reference.

Comment: Naturally, I've read through the docs in an effort to understand but they confused me.  and putting `{% nav_links %}` anywhere in my `navigation.html` just causes an 'Invalid block tag: "nav_links" error

Comment: Again, that was a typo on SO, I meant `nav_links`.  I am experimenting with your answer, will return soon.

Comment: Looks like the error is somewhere else. Could you please check some obvious stuff, e.g. whether the app with the custom tag is in the INSTALLED_APPS? Do you have correct project layout (e.g. `templatetags` folder is named appropriately, resides on top level of application folder structure and contains `__init__.py`)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Your answer lead me to the solution.  I did as you explained, and realized that I had misinterpreted your answer and tried to use `{% nav_links %}` in navigation.html instead of catalog.html, which when I thought about it made no sense so I reorganized them the way they should go and all worked out.  I was simply misunderstanding how those inclusion decorators operated.  Hopefully now that I get it I can read the docs again and it will make more sense.  Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's just a copy paste error or not but `return {'flatpage_list': flatpage_list` isn't closed properly `return {'flatpage_list': flatpage_list}`

Also could this be something more suited for a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)?

---

EDIT: After reading the other answer, I realized what you are trying to do, when you were using the `{% include ... %}` tag it seemed like you just wanted to populate the `flatpage_list`

Comment: Context processor would do the trick, but custom template tags is somewhat more appropriate for this type of task, as with processor you only get a context variable in all the templates, but you still have to use it somehow. Custom inclusion tags addresses both providing and consuming data.

Comment: Yea, I thought that since he was also calling `{%  include "tags/navigation.html" %}` that he was trying to use the custom tags to simply populate the list.